# Was ist richtig: aufs Brot oder auf dem Brot?

Tags: preposition, wechselpraeposition

Ich bin auf diesen Satz gestoßen: Möchtest du Butter **aufs Brot** oder nur Käse?

Ich bin mir nicht sicher, ob er in Ordnung ist.

Was ist richtig: *aufs Brot* oder *auf dem Brot*?

Answer (score 5):

Beides ist richtig, aber die beiden Varianten haben (geringfügig) unterschiedliche Bedeutung.

"auf dem Brot" ist ein Ort, während "auf's Brot" (was eine Verkürzung von "auf das Brot" ist) eine Richtungsangabe ist. Um das an einem Vergleich zu zeigen:

> Ich klettere auf's Dach.
> Ich stehe auf dem Dach.

Wenn Du also was "auf's Brot" möchtest, dann willst Du, daß dieses dorthin plaziert wird. Willst Du etwas "auf dem Brot", dann willst Du, daß es sich bereits dort befinden möge.

Comment: Im Detail möchte ich korrigieren. Du könntest für Deine Partnerin im Hotel zum Frühstücksbuffet gehen, und ihr einen Teller mitbringen wollen mit Brot und Käse und eventuell einem kl. Stück Butter in Alufolie verpackt und obwohl Du sie ihr nicht drauf schmieren willst beides fragen, implizierend dass sie sich die Butter schon selbst drauf machen wird.

Comment: Die Korrekte Rechtschreibung ist ["aufs"](https://www.duden.de/haeufige_fehler/auf-s).

Answer (score 1):

"Möchtest" wäre ja eigentlich ein Modalverb, und wir  brauchen einen Infinitiv dazu. Der wird oft weggelassen: "Möchtest du ein Eis?" versteht man als "Möchtest du ein Eis bekommen?".

In dem Beispiel hängt es also davon ab, welches Verb wir uns zum Modalverb dazudenken:

"Möchtest du Butter auf dem Brot haben?"

"Möchtest du Butter auf das Brot gestrichen bekommen?"